# How to Associate Posts with Pages

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, pages

This is more of a "how does this work", kind of question than a code question, though some code may be involved. I've been Googling, and reading other questions about custom post types and taxonomies, and haven't come across an answer that really suits my dilemma.

Ideally, this is what I'm going for:

I have a page titled "Guests". When you go to that page, it lists all of the pages that have a profile of each guest (one page per guest/one guest per page), with a thumbnail and a brief excerpt. When you click on one of the excerpted pages, you get the full biography of the guest, and a carousel of all the videos (posts) which feature that specific guest. The flow is basically, "Guests">"(Guest's Name)">"(Guest's Name)'s Videos".

My dilemma:

I realize that using categories for each individual guest is not a good idea. Would a custom post type and taxonomies be appropriate for this?

There will be no limit to the number of guests (and, thus, the number of profile pages) that would need to be created. From what I've been reading, that doesn't seem like the proper use of custom post types. And, I'm also confused as to how to customize WP_Query args to get the specific video posts for each guest to show up on their own profile (I can't give pages categories, and I can't give posts parents).

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend installing an easy to use custom post type plugin like [Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/).

From there, you can create a custom post type called Guests.

After that, I would to create some custom fields for these guests, such as a name, a multi-line field for biography, etc...

The only variable I'm not 100% sure about is the video bit. If you're adding these videos yourself, then you could add them as a custom field, where you chose to either go with the URL of the video or perhaps the embed code, then in your template you would loop through these custom fields to show each of the videos for the guest.

If the guests will be responsible for posting their own videos, then I would scrap all of the above content and consider setting up a WordPress installation with a role manager and a custom post type for videos only. Then you can just show these per author as if they were posts.

Comment: Guests won't be responsible for posting their own videos. This was very helpful, thank you.